# WordPress Include woocommerce-products in a one-page layout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I'm making a one-page-site for a client, which includes a webshop. Now each WP-pages makes up a slide. The slides uses different theme-templates and in one of the slides called "Shop" I want to display all WooCommerce-products (it uses the template `slide-shop.php` .
Right now the `<ul class="products">` is echoed, however the content of it is empty. If you go to the page url (`site.com/shop`) all products show fine.

one-page.php:

```
 <?php 
    $pages = get_pages(array('sort_column' => 'menu_order'));
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
        $page_ID = $page_data->ID;
        //$slug = $page_data->post_name;
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
        $title = $page_data->post_title;
        $template = get_page_template_slug( $page_ID );
        $i++; 
?>  

<section id="slide-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="slide cf">
    <div class="slide-wrap cf">         
        <div class="slide-con item cf" >            
            <?php include($template); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>  
<?php 
    } /*end foreach*/
?>
```

slide-shop.php:

```
/*
 Template Name: Slide w. shop
 */
?> 
    <div class="slide-header cf">
        <h2><?php echo $title ?></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-body cf">
        <div class="col d-1of2 cf">
            <?php echo $content ?>

        </div>

        <div class="col d-1of2 cf">
                <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i can't understand what you exactly want ? i think you want to show your all wooocmmerce product on single page

Comment: Sorry if I'm unclear. So I have a one-page-site with a number of slides that uses different page-templates (each slide is a page in wp-admin). One of the slides should display the woocommerce-products created by the admin but its not working.

Comment: any url ?? where i checked it

Comment: Sorry, working locally :/

Comment: you can use shortcode for showing product or you can get product by id ......please try and see doc file of your theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Documentation](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-woocommerce_content.html) for `woocommerce_content` states:

> This function is only used in the optional 'woocommerce.php' template. which people can add to their themes to add basic woocommerce support. without hooks or modifying core templates.

So in your case the solution would be to replace

`<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>`

with

`<?php echo do_shortcode("[products]"); ?>`

That should get the products to appear in your slide.

Comment: Cheers that fixed it nice and simply :)

Comment: BTW, this only displays the products thumbnail, title & price. What if I wished to echo the product-content from the WYSIWYG-editor, how would I do this?

Comment: In that case you'll need to run your own WP_Query, fetching all the products and then in the loop you can use `the_content()` to display the content from WYSIWYG editor. If you go this route you'll have to display everything manually, price is stored as custom meta, so you'll need to use `get_post_meta`